# Amazon Connect: why does agent transfer result in tardy arrival of DISCONNECTED contact event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am using Amazon Connect Quick Connects to facilitate call transfers between the 1st agent who receives a call and a 2nd agent who completes it.  The workflow is something like this:

1. 1st agent Accepts the call (from CCP -- `Contact Control Panel`).
2. Contact Event **CONNECTED_TO_AGENT** is triggered for 1st leg of call.
3. 1st agent left-clicks on Quick Connects and then left-double-clicks on the first listed Quick Connect.
4. Contact Event **QUEUED** is triggered for 1st leg of call.
5. 2nd agent presses Accept to receive an inbound call.
6. Contact Event **CONNECTED_TO_AGENT** is triggered for 2nd leg of call.
7. 1st agent presses Join and then eventually presses Leave or the red hang-up button to terminate 1st leg.
8. When 2nd leg of calls ends with 2nd agent, a Contact Event **DISCONNECTED** is generated for the 2nd agent.
9. Finally, a Contact Event **DISCONNECTED** is generated for the 1st agent.

Obviously, what's troubling about this workflow is that the 1st agent apparently is not DISCONNECTED until the 2nd leg of the call is completed.  This to my thinking is not right.

QUESTION:  is there some way to configure Amazon Connect (Eg, Contact Flows) so that in the example detailed here, a **DISCONNECTED** Contact Event is triggered when the 1st leg of the call is terminated?

**Reverse chronological logs of Contact Events:**

```
"@timestamp",msg,"kubernetes.container_name"
"Jan 24, 2024 @ 17:35:00.236","WrappedContactEvent: &{Version:0 Id:d0cf79c4-0830-cc66-41bc-ecf6a5e77adb DetailType:Amazon Connect Contact Event Source:aws.connect Account:012345678901 Time:2024-01-25T01:34:59Z Region:us-west-2 Resources:[arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/contact/c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95] Detail:{EventType:DISCONNECTED ContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 InitialContactId: PreviousContactId: InstanceArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a Channel:VOICE QueueInfo:{QueueArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/queue/e6aee93a-ce38-48b9-a53f-b32983d8e0e7 QueueType:STANDARD} AgentInfo:{AgentArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/agent/a97df283-81bc-4f05-b3dd-6a0b9b5e3b8a ConnectedToAgentTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:33:20.015Z} InitiationMethod:INBOUND RelatedContactId: InitiationTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:32:58.605Z ConnectedToSystemTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:32:59.195Z DisconnectTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:34:59.847Z}}","amzn-conn"
"Jan 24, 2024 @ 17:35:00.136","WrappedContactEvent: &{Version:0 Id:b5b3d42f-0eb7-3a7a-61cc-8441ec83a4b9 DetailType:Amazon Connect Contact Event Source:aws.connect Account:012345678901 Time:2024-01-25T01:34:59Z Region:us-west-2 Resources:[arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/contact/439b02d4-955d-44d9-9997-8e8bbc5ef3a2] Detail:{EventType:DISCONNECTED ContactId:439b02d4-955d-44d9-9997-8e8bbc5ef3a2 InitialContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 PreviousContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 InstanceArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a Channel:VOICE QueueInfo:{QueueArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/queue/a31000f7-3e8f-429e-9491-b4df88a1b636 QueueType:STANDARD} AgentInfo:{AgentArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/agent/4ac0e9b8-df9f-4d53-a249-fa2ae6a67269 ConnectedToAgentTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:34:09.949Z} InitiationMethod:TRANSFER RelatedContactId: InitiationTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:34:00.140Z ConnectedToSystemTimestamp: DisconnectTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:34:59.740Z}}","amzn-conn"
"Jan 24, 2024 @ 17:34:10.566","WrappedContactEvent: &{Version:0 Id:c0687bff-6988-b936-b01c-1e01b3e664a1 DetailType:Amazon Connect Contact Event Source:aws.connect Account:012345678901 Time:2024-01-25T01:34:10Z Region:us-west-2 Resources:[arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/contact/439b02d4-955d-44d9-9997-8e8bbc5ef3a2] Detail:{EventType:CONNECTED_TO_AGENT ContactId:439b02d4-955d-44d9-9997-8e8bbc5ef3a2 InitialContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 PreviousContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 InstanceArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a Channel:VOICE QueueInfo:{QueueArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/queue/a31000f7-3e8f-429e-9491-b4df88a1b636 QueueType:STANDARD} AgentInfo:{AgentArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/agent/4ac0e9b8-df9f-4d53-a249-fa2ae6a67269 ConnectedToAgentTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:34:09.949Z} InitiationMethod:TRANSFER RelatedContactId: InitiationTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:34:00.140Z ConnectedToSystemTimestamp: DisconnectTimestamp:}}","amzn-conn"
"Jan 24, 2024 @ 17:34:04.876","WrappedContactEvent: &{Version:0 Id:74b5ddc8-10ce-e743-40d9-3b89a0e817f5 DetailType:Amazon Connect Contact Event Source:aws.connect Account:012345678901 Time:2024-01-25T01:34:04Z Region:us-west-2 Resources:[arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/contact/439b02d4-955d-44d9-9997-8e8bbc5ef3a2] Detail:{EventType:QUEUED ContactId:439b02d4-955d-44d9-9997-8e8bbc5ef3a2 InitialContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 PreviousContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 InstanceArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a Channel:VOICE QueueInfo:{QueueArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/queue/a31000f7-3e8f-429e-9491-b4df88a1b636 QueueType:STANDARD} AgentInfo:{AgentArn: ConnectedToAgentTimestamp:} InitiationMethod:TRANSFER RelatedContactId: InitiationTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:34:00.140Z ConnectedToSystemTimestamp: DisconnectTimestamp:}}","amzn-conn"
"Jan 24, 2024 @ 17:34:00.977","WrappedContactEvent: &{Version:0 Id:e46c928c-7997-0e63-0f9a-f797c90d9ba9 DetailType:Amazon Connect Contact Event Source:aws.connect Account:012345678901 Time:2024-01-25T01:34:00Z Region:us-west-2 Resources:[arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/contact/439b02d4-955d-44d9-9997-8e8bbc5ef3a2] Detail:{EventType:INITIATED ContactId:439b02d4-955d-44d9-9997-8e8bbc5ef3a2 InitialContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 PreviousContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 InstanceArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a Channel:VOICE QueueInfo:{QueueArn: QueueType:} AgentInfo:{AgentArn: ConnectedToAgentTimestamp:} InitiationMethod:TRANSFER RelatedContactId: InitiationTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:34:00.140Z ConnectedToSystemTimestamp: DisconnectTimestamp:}}","amzn-conn"
"Jan 24, 2024 @ 17:33:20.710","WrappedContactEvent: &{Version:0 Id:85cf526d-79da-c423-f2dc-afe94e65fcf8 DetailType:Amazon Connect Contact Event Source:aws.connect Account:012345678901 Time:2024-01-25T01:33:20Z Region:us-west-2 Resources:[arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/contact/c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95] Detail:{EventType:CONNECTED_TO_AGENT ContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 InitialContactId: PreviousContactId: InstanceArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a Channel:VOICE QueueInfo:{QueueArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/queue/e6aee93a-ce38-48b9-a53f-b32983d8e0e7 QueueType:STANDARD} AgentInfo:{AgentArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/agent/a97df283-81bc-4f05-b3dd-6a0b9b5e3b8a ConnectedToAgentTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:33:20.015Z} InitiationMethod:INBOUND RelatedContactId: InitiationTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:32:58.605Z ConnectedToSystemTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:32:59.195Z DisconnectTimestamp:}}","amzn-conn"
"Jan 24, 2024 @ 17:33:10.325","WrappedContactEvent: &{Version:0 Id:b1a5e1a1-fcf2-88ce-3364-986bfad89253 DetailType:Amazon Connect Contact Event Source:aws.connect Account:012345678901 Time:2024-01-25T01:33:09Z Region:us-west-2 Resources:[arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/contact/c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95] Detail:{EventType:QUEUED ContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 InitialContactId: PreviousContactId: InstanceArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a Channel:VOICE QueueInfo:{QueueArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/queue/e6aee93a-ce38-48b9-a53f-b32983d8e0e7 QueueType:STANDARD} AgentInfo:{AgentArn: ConnectedToAgentTimestamp:} InitiationMethod:INBOUND RelatedContactId: InitiationTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:32:58.605Z ConnectedToSystemTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:32:59.195Z DisconnectTimestamp:}}","amzn-conn"
"Jan 24, 2024 @ 17:33:03.156","WrappedContactEvent: &{Version:0 Id:3a2174be-e1aa-18ba-14da-5de67d250b05 DetailType:Amazon Connect Contact Event Source:aws.connect Account:012345678901 Time:2024-01-25T01:33:02Z Region:us-west-2 Resources:[arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/contact/c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95] Detail:{EventType:CONTACT_DATA_UPDATED ContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 InitialContactId: PreviousContactId: InstanceArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a Channel:VOICE QueueInfo:{QueueArn: QueueType:} AgentInfo:{AgentArn: ConnectedToAgentTimestamp:} InitiationMethod:INBOUND RelatedContactId: InitiationTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:32:58.605Z ConnectedToSystemTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:32:59.195Z DisconnectTimestamp:}}","amzn-conn"
"Jan 24, 2024 @ 17:33:00.358","WrappedContactEvent: &{Version:0 Id:83cf685c-2fca-96ab-c2f4-56cbeb1d9ad3 DetailType:Amazon Connect Contact Event Source:aws.connect Account:012345678901 Time:2024-01-25T01:32:59Z Region:us-west-2 Resources:[arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/contact/c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95] Detail:{EventType:CONNECTED_TO_SYSTEM ContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 InitialContactId: PreviousContactId: InstanceArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a Channel:VOICE QueueInfo:{QueueArn: QueueType:} AgentInfo:{AgentArn: ConnectedToAgentTimestamp:} InitiationMethod:INBOUND RelatedContactId: InitiationTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:32:58.605Z ConnectedToSystemTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:32:59.195Z DisconnectTimestamp:}}","amzn-conn"
"Jan 24, 2024 @ 17:32:59.867","WrappedContactEvent: &{Version:0 Id:1f32de41-8c50-9d62-04e4-b06d77c9eeb8 DetailType:Amazon Connect Contact Event Source:aws.connect Account:012345678901 Time:2024-01-25T01:32:58Z Region:us-west-2 Resources:[arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a/contact/c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95] Detail:{EventType:INITIATED ContactId:c8628f9b-78f9-4ae3-82ec-8f2eaebdad95 InitialContactId: PreviousContactId: InstanceArn:arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:012345678901:instance/85fef571-25fc-4c38-881a-df4dbf150a3a Channel:VOICE QueueInfo:{QueueArn: QueueType:} AgentInfo:{AgentArn: ConnectedToAgentTimestamp:} InitiationMethod:INBOUND RelatedContactId: InitiationTimestamp:2024-01-25T01:32:58.605Z ConnectedToSystemTimestamp: DisconnectTimestamp:}}","amzn-conn"
```

Answer (score 0):

In #4, are you sure the contact is not QUEUED on the second leg?

To your question, it does sound weird. 1st agent is definitely disconnected when they press the red end call button. Note, however, that events are not guaranteed to be in order. Have you looked at the timestamps?

Comment: I'll take a look at timestamps.  If contact events are not chronological, then how can we depend on the stream of contact events as a reliable source for call-state transitions?  Surely they must be in order.

Comment: Good question, but this is quite typical in distributed system architecture. Amazon Connect clearly says you should rely on timestamps rather than on event arrival order (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/contact-events.html#subscribe-contact-events). The solution is to buffer the data and sort the events on the consumer's side, but obviously you'd need to take some assumptions on the buffer size and the expected delay.

Comment: I just added logs to the end of the original posting; said logs show clearly what I mean.  Scroll right, and you can see `DISCONNECTED` event happens more or less at the same time for both call legs.  I just don't see how this can possibly be correct behavior.

Comment: Interesting. I'm just checking - are you testing with native CCP or custom softphone? did agent #1 leave ACW after they hung up? Also, closely reading the docs, "DisconnectTimestamp" is "The date and time that the customer endpoint disconnected from Amazon Connect". So literally speaking it explains the logs because it's the same customer talking to both legs. If that's true, it is not clear how to get the disconnection time of the agent - you might need to correlate with the agent event stream...

Comment: Native CCP.  Agent #1 hung up, pressed the Close or Completed Contact button, but remained in `Available` status with CCP open.  See data model for Contact Events:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/contact-events.html#contact-events-data-model ... `DISCONNECTED` definition is consistent with what you said.  What seems to be missing is an event such as `DISCONNECTED_FROM_AGENT`.  I might be able to leverage `QUEUED` for our needs, but that is risky.

Comment: There is also "TransferCompletedTimestamp" attribute on the CTR event records which might be helpful. I'm not sure if that exist on Kinesis events though.

Comment: Contact Trace events are not real-time.  I am going to use an ad hoc test for ascertaining whether an agent has transferred the call:  if the contact is in state `CONNECTED_TO_AGENT` and then the contact transitions to `QUEUED`, I will just assume that a transfer has happened.  This probably will work, but is gross and obviously prone to inducing buggy behavior.  Amazon should really add a new state that unambiguously characterizes the agent-disconnect on transfers.

Comment: Yeah. It won't work for warm transfer scenarios, where both agents A & B are connected at the same time. But if that's not a possible scenario in your setup then great!